# Script not restarting the remote machines. Goal is to run this from a server and have it restart a number of machines

Tags: vbscript

It runs, but it does not restart the machines. I cannot understand why this would not restart the machines.

```
Option Explicit
call FixedArray

sub FixedArray
dim strCompName(16)
strCompName(0) = "X"
strCompName(1) = "Y"
dim strShutdown
Dim objShell
Dim i
for i = 0 to UBound(strCompName)
    strShutdown = "shutdown -r -t 0 -f -m\\" & strCompName(i)
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run strShutdown
WScript.Quit    
next
end sub
```

Comment: Read the error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Running the script:

- invokes `shutdown -r -t 0 -f -m\\X` (syntax error: maybe a missing space in `-m \\X` ?), and
- performs `WScript.Quit` immediately so that the `for-next` *loop* degrades.

After clearing above bugs, the script invokes:

- `shutdown -r -t 0 -f -m \\X`
- `shutdown -r -t 0 -f -m \\Y`
- and then `shutdown -r -t 0 -f -m \\` (wrong ) multiple times because `strCompName(i)` is `Empty` for each `i` between 2 and 16.

The script could be as follows (in its *debugging* version with `objShell.Run strShutdown` commented up):

```
Option Explicit
Dim sR
sR = Wscript.ScriptName 
call FixedArray
Wscript.Echo sR
WScript.Quit    

sub FixedArray
  dim strCompName(16)
  strCompName(0) = "X"
  strCompName(1) = "Y"
  dim strShutdown
  Dim objShell
  Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
  Dim i
  for i = 0 to UBound(strCompName)
    If VarType(strCompName(i)) = 8 Then         ' 8 = String '
      strShutdown = "shutdown -r -t 0 -f -m \\" & strCompName(i)
      '' objShell.Run strShutdown
      sR = sR & vbNewLine & CStr(i) & vbTab & strShutDown
    End If
  next
end sub
```

Comment: Where is your CStr(i) being pulled from? it is blue, but mine is not also my 8 is not read? i am assuming its because it is not identifying correctly? @ JosefZ

Comment: @adamp [Use the `CStr` function to provide conversions from any data type to a _String_ subtype](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/0zk841e9(v=vs.84)) in [VBScript Language Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/d1wf56tt(v=vs.84)).